# Why is $\langle c \cdot f|g\rangle=c^*\langle f|g\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, notation, complex-numbers

Why is $\langle c \cdot f|g\rangle=c^*\langle f|g\rangle$?

$c$ is a complex number and $c^*$ is the conjugate. I think that $\langle c \cdot f|g\rangle=c\langle f|g\rangle$ because that's how scalar multiplication works with vectors' dot products works (since I compare $\langle f|g\rangle$ to $\vec{f}\cdot\vec{g}$), but why do we take the complex *conjugate* instead?

Answer (score 5):

We define the inner product to be conjugate symmetric (i.e. $\langle f,g\rangle = \overline{\langle g, f\rangle}$) because we'd like $\langle f,f\rangle$ to serve as a viable candidate for the (squared) norm $\Vert f \Vert^2$, and the conjugate symmetry implies that $\langle f,f\rangle$ is real.

From there, conjugate symmetry along with linearity in the second argument implies that
$$\langle c\cdot f,g\rangle = \overline{\langle g,c \cdot f\rangle} = \overline{c \langle g,f\rangle} = c^* \overline{\langle g,f\rangle} = c^* \langle f,g\rangle$$

If we are to have a complex vector space with a norm-inducing inner product, we can only impose full linearity on one of the arguments, and have to settle for conjugate linearity in the other.

Comment: Note: In mathematics the inner product is often defined to be linear in the first argument and antilinear (i.e. have complex conjugation of factors) in the second.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can do this since notation is subjective, but it won't be standard.

We usually denote the product between a scalar and a vector as
$$c|f\rangle=|c\ f\rangle$$

And we also have
$$\langle f|=|f\rangle^\dagger$$

Therefore
$$\langle c\ f|=|c\ f\rangle^\dagger=\left(c|f\rangle\right)^\dagger=c^*\langle f|$$

This is where the complex conjugate comes from.  You can then apply this to the inner product in question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of definition. Consider a Vector space $(V,+,\cdot,\mathbb{C})$ defined on the complex field.

A **Sesquilinear form** is a map:
$$q:V\times V\to\mathbb{C}$$
such that it is linear in the second argument and anti-linear in the first, i.e.
$$\forall v_1,v_2,w\in V,\forall\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb{C}:\quad\quad q(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2,w)=\bar{\alpha}_1q(v_1,w)+\bar{\alpha}_2q(v_2,w)$$
$$\forall w_1,w_2,vin V,\forall\beta_1,\beta_2\in\mathbb{C}:\quad\quad q(v,\beta_1w_1+\beta_2w_2)=\beta_1q(v,w_1)+\beta_2q(v,w_2)$$
Now, a sesquilinear form $q$ is said to be **Hermitian** if:
$$\forall v,w\in V:\quad\quad q(v,w)=\overline{q(v,w)}$$
Moreover, a sesquilinear form $q$ is said to be non-degenerate if:
$$(\forall w\in V:\quad q(v,w)=0)\implies(v=0)$$
and $q$ is definite positive if:
$$\forall v\in V:\quad\quad q(v,v)\geq0\text{    with }=0\iff v=0$$
We can define an **Hermitian Scalar Product** as a sesquilinear form $q$ such that it is Hermitian and definite positive.

An Hilbert space is a $(\mathscr{H},+,\cdot,\mathbb{C},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ hermitian product such that this vector space is **complete**.

In quantum mechanics we consider this type of vector spaces, in which it is defined this inner product, which is anti-linear in the first argument and linear in the second.